# Is there a way to program to run on a given time?

Tags: java, cmd

I've made my first simple bot and I want it to run through CMD on a given time, example:

Run every Tuesday 5pm.

I already set the path on a Bat file to run it, just wondering if there's a way or command to run on time.

Comment: Windows has a "task scheduler" that lets you do that. That should be easier than writing a program for this.

Comment: Meanwhile Linux has cron.

Comment: @Lucas Whats your Operating System, Widows or Linux? I will write the commands for you let me know!!

Comment: @ShivaShinde Its on Windows, but thanks to f1sh I already did what I needed, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the GUI for Task Scheduler. Or type `schtasks /?` and `schtasks /create /?`.

This starts notepad at 7pm weekly.

```
schtasks /create /tn test /tr notepad.exe /sc weekly /st 19:00
```

Comment: In case I can't user the Scheduler anymore, I will use this code.